# Hbase write performance degrades afer 4-5 days of restart

Tags: performance, hbase, apache-phoenix

We are facing this issue in our cluster where we use phoenix to write the data. We have observed our jobs works fine initially. But after few days (4-5 days) we see drastic increase in our job time (4 mins to 30 mins). Input data size is almost same. And restarting hbase solves the issue for the next 4-5 days.

We have 70 region servers of size 128G each. 50k(per region server)*70(no of region servers) puts per job.

From the RS logs I can see increase in responseTooSlow warning logs frequency from 40k/day to 280k/day but response time is less than 1000ms in those logs.

2018-04-18 00:00:07,831 WARN  [RW.default.writeRpcServer.handler=10,queue=4,port=16020] ipc.RpcServer: (responseTooSlow): {"call":"Multi(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MultiRequest)","starttimems":1524009607697,"responsesize":106,"method":"Multi","processingtimems":134,"client":"192.168.25.70:54718","queuetimems":0,"class":"HRegionServer"}

Comment: Check if HBase is spending too much time in GC or in compacting HFiles, if there is any lean period where writes are low, schedule a major-compaction during that time, I would recommend to log and analyze your GC activity

Comment: @mbaxi thanks for the reply. We have disabled major compaction but I can see minor compaction running. On a single RS log per hour 3-4 compaction logs are present and they are taking time from few seconds to 10 mins. I don't see much GC pause logs (Detected pause in JVM or host machine). only 1 or 2 pause log entries per region server per day with time less than 5 sec.

Comment: There can be multiple factors that can be causing these warnings, what is the volume of reads? Is your data distributed evenly across all the regions? You should also  check rpc call queues settings, separate read and write queues. Your heap space is also on higher side so getting GC logs enabled and analyzing those would be helpful,, mixed GCs can also impact performance.

Comment: Also since auto major compaction is disabled are you manually triggering it? What is the overall size of your table? try tuning phoenix batch size to a smaller number...

Comment: Table size is around 1.1T. This table has more than 2000 regions could this be causing issue ? and after hbase restart system runs fine for 5-6 days.